# Сравнение адресов Python

Tags: python, строки

Пытаюсь разобраться, как сравнить строки
Примеры строк

```
1. г. Москва, вн.тер.г. муниципальный округ Тверской, ул Кузнецкий Мост, д. 4/3, стр. 1, этаж МАНСАРДНЫЙ, ПОМ. I, ком. 413
2. г. Москва Тверской ул Кузнецкий Мост д. 4/3 стр. 1

3. 105005 г. Москва 2-я Бауманская ул. 5 стр. 1
4. 105005 г. Москва ул. Радио д. 20
```

Как видно, строки 1 и 2 содержат в целом одинаковый адрес. А строки 3 и 4 разный.
Я не могу понять, как сделать,чтобы программа выдавала, что 1 и 2 адрес - один и тот же.
Даже не знаю  с чего начать...

Comment: наташа вам не подойдёт ? https://habr.com/ru/post/516098/

Comment: Мне кажется нет..Может тут нужен более менее простой скрипт с набором правил

Comment: С чего начать: описываете полный набор правил на человеческом языке, потом реализуете в коде (например, через замену или вытаскивание только нужных частей по регулярным выражениям).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- почистить всякий мусор
- использовать нечёткое сравнение

В первом приближении может выглядеть так:

```
import re
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

junk_words = [
r'вн\.тер\.г\.',
'муниципальный округ',
r'этаж \w+',
r'ПОМ\. \w+',
r'ком\. \w+',
r'\,']
junk_re = re.compile('|'.join(f'{w}' for w in junk_words), re.IGNORECASE)

addresses = [
'г. Москва, вн.тер.г. муниципальный округ Тверской, ул Кузнецкий Мост, д. 4/3, стр. 1, этаж МАНСАРДНЫЙ, ПОМ. I, ком. 413',
'г. Москва Тверской ул Кузнецкий Мост д. 4/3 стр. 1',
'105005 г. Москва 2-я Бауманская ул. 5 стр. 1',
'105005 г. Москва ул. Радио д. 20',
]

addr_processed = [junk_re.sub('', addr).strip() for addr in addresses]
print('\n'.join(addr_processed))

for i,w1 in enumerate(addr_processed):
    for j,w2 in enumerate(addr_processed):
        if i >= j:
            continue
        print(i, j, fuzz.ratio(w1.lower(),w2.lower()))
```

Почищенные от ненужной информации адреса:

```
г. Москва   Тверской ул Кузнецкий Мост д. 4/3 стр. 1
г. Москва Тверской ул Кузнецкий Мост д. 4/3 стр. 1
105005 г. Москва 2-я Бауманская ул. 5 стр. 1
105005 г. Москва ул. Радио д. 20
```

Результаты сравнения:

```
0 1 98
0 2 52
0 3 45
1 2 51
1 3 46
2 3 63
```

Обычно рейтинг где-то >95 означает, что данные можно считать совпадающими. В данном случае совпадают 1-й и 2-й адреса, остальные сравнения дают очень маленький рейтинг. Основные проблемы бывают на рейтинге от 85 до 95, но дополнительная чистка/нормализация данных может помочь - надо смотреть, где алгоритм не справляется и добавлять ещё преобразований данных.

Но вообще может получиться и так, что вы в итоге утонете в этих преобразованиях данных. В общем случае это довольно нетривиальная задача и она может оказаться гораздо сложнее, чем выглядит на первый взгляд.

Comment: Ещё можно посмотреть в сторону `difflib.SequenceMatcher().ratio()` или `Levenshtein.ratio()`. Но всё-равно, к примеру, строки `105005 г. Москва ул. Радио д. 20` и `105005 г. Москва ул. Радио д. 21` дадут бОльшую одинаковость, чем даже почищенные 1 и 2 строки. В общем, задача не тривиальна. По хорошему, надо парсить каждый адрес в структуру (город, улица, дом, корпус, и т.д.) и уже эти структуры сравнивать на "похожесть".

Comment: @GrAnd Кстати, ценное замечание. У нас в конторе это решалось просто - брали одни только цифры из обоих строк и если такие чисто цифровые строки не совпадали, то сразу рейтинг ставился ноль. Хотя опять же надо смотреть на примеры, если где-то ошибутся с индексом или напишут какую-то ещё лишнюю цифровую инфу, это сразу всё сломает. В общем, процесс творческий, да

Comment: @GrAnd И да, продвинутые чуваки делают именно как вы сказали - вычленяют сущности и заполняют инфу в них. Но тут то просили метод попроще. Моим методом можно уже сразу начать что-то делать, а там нужна долгая подготовка чтобы хоть что-то начать делать. Хотя можно конечно из Наташи опять же взять экстрактор адресов для начала.

Comment: В целом,направление решения мне понятно. Благодарю

Comment: @Newman Учтите наши комментарии тут про близость рейтингов адресов с похожими номерами домов, например. С этим что-то придётся делать дополнительно. Сделайте отдельную функцию для подсчёта рейтинга и там это как-то учтите вместе со значением `fuzz.ratio`.